# How to generate secret key to get TOTP for HMAC SHA512 comply with RFC6238 and RFC4086?

Tags: java, hmac, totp

I have to make an HTTP POST request to the URL http://example.com/test which contains the JSON string as a body part, headers "Content-Type:application/json" and "Authorization: Basic userid:password". userid is abc@example.com and password must be 10-digit time-based one time password comply with RFC6238 TOTP using HMAC-SHA-512 for the hash function.

Token shared secret should be "abc@example.comTEXT5" without double quotations.

So, to achieve above I modified the Java code of RFC6238 [RC6238 TOTP Algo](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238)

To get TOTP, I converted the shared secret "abc@example.comTEXT5" to HMAC-SHA512 using [online converter tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html)  as well some codes which generate the same 128 character length HEX code

Making the request always responses that "TOTP is wrong".

I noticed that I generated the wrong secret key, so there is the wrong TOTP. So, how can I generate the correct secret key that complies HMAC-SHA512 with Java code of RFC6238 algorithm?

There is default key as seed on the algorithm:

```
String seed64 = "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
         "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
         "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930" +
         "31323334";
```

How can I get such seed64 for my shared secret "abc@example.comTEXT5"?
My modified code is [10 digit TOTP](https://gist.github.com/sah-arjun/2507a0b097f4917603ef4cf7c4be12b4)

I appreciate help from everyone!

Answer (score 7):

The example 64 byte seed in [Appendix A of RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238#appendix-A) is the HEX encoded version of the ASCII secret `12345678901234567890` provided in [Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238#appendix-B) which contains the truth table.

```
ASCII 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0
HEX   31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30
```

If you want to convert your shared secret using the same pattern, you would convert `abc@example.comTEXT5` to HEX in string format if you're using the example code provided in Appendix A.

This would come out to the following HEX string :

`616263406578616D706C652E636F6D5445585435`

To build the example 64 byte seed used for the SHA-512 hash the initial 20 bytes are repeated to make 64 bytes total to achieve an optimal key length for the SHA-512 hash.

Doing the same with your example string would produce the following seed:

```
String seed64 = "616263406578616D706C652E636F6D5445585435" +
         "616263406578616D706C652E636F6D5445585435" +
         "616263406578616D706C652E636F6D5445585435" +
         "61626340";
```

If you use the rest of the example code to calculate the time step and request a 10 digit TOTP code, I assume it will work for you.

If you are using something like this in production, you may wish to use a more randomly generated secret.

For example, to generate a 64 byte secret for SHA-512, you could do something like:

```
  public static String generateRawSecret(int length) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[length];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(buf);
    String rawSecret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(buf);
    return rawSecret.substring(1, length + 1);
  }

  // Random 64 byte secret
  String secret = generateRawSecret(64);
```

It looks like you've already got most of this coded, but if you're looking for some additional Java examples, the following link is a GitHub project that has a simple utility class with a bunch of tests. https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-2FA

Comment: Thanks @robotdan for your effort, your GitHub repo is useful and looking at it. But for now, I have achieved my goal using Python.

Comment: @Arjun I am stuck with the same issue. Can you share what python solution you used? Thanks.

Comment: Should we have 128 characters in base64?

Comment: will the generated raw secret in Base64 be encoded again in Base32? since the TOTP's shared secret should be Base32 encoded